# Using the python docker module, how can I get the version tag of an image?

Tags: python, docker, dockerpy

**TL;DR** Using the python docker module, how can I get the version of an image?

When calling `docker images` the version is nicely broken out under the **Tag** column which would look somethin like. The following.

| REPOSITORY | TAG | IMAGE ID | CREATED | SIZE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| python | latest | abc123abc123 | 1 year ago | 3.14MB |

What is the simplest way to get the version tag (e.g. latest) when using the python API?  For example,

```
image = docker.from_env().images.list(filters = { 'reference' : 'python'})[0]
repo_tag = image.attrs['RepoTags']
print("repo_tag") # python:latest
version = repo_tag.split(":")[1]
```

Is there a more direct method instead of doing a `.split`?

Comment: Couldn't find one, but perhaps use `.tags` to at least remove *some* code (and use negative indexing in case the tag itself has a colon): `image.tags[0].split(':')[-1]` (FWIW your example is also missing `image.attrs['RepoTags'][0]`)

Comment: I'm still struggling with this stuff, but each tag for an image amounts to a "version" because each tag is supposed to uniquely identify an image within a repository. The business of stuff after the ":" in a tag is only a useful convention, e.g. "latest". Unless I misunderstand, the *order* of tags on an image is not material; each tag is a unique identifier within the repository. Please correct me.